# How to do $\int_{ }^{ }\frac{e^{12t} }{e^{24t}+2e^{12t}+1}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I do the following:

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{e^{12t}}{e^{24t}+2e^{12t}+1}dt$$

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJp2w.png)

Comment: Enforce the substitution $e^{12 t}\mapsto t$ and complete the square.

Comment: Homework is assigned for a reason...getting others to do it for you defeats that reason.

Comment: omg all these downvotes lol i wanted to post my answer but will heep it for me ...lol

Comment: @Jae What has been tried?

Comment: @dromastyx tsemo got the right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set $u=e^{12t}$, $du=12udt$, $\int{{e^{12t}\over{e^{24t}+2e^{12t}+1}}}dt$

$={1\over{12}}\int{1\over{(1+u)^2}}du=-{1\over{12}}{1\over{1+u}}=-{1\over{12}}{1\over{1+e^{12t}}}.$

Comment: forgot to add +C, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Solve by substituition with $e^{12t}=x\implies 12e^{12t}dt=dx$

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{e^{12t}}{e^{24t}+2e^{12t}+1}dt=\frac1{12}\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{x^2+2x+1}dx=\frac1{12}\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

$$\frac{e^{12t}}{e^{24t}+2e^{12t}+1}=\frac{e^{12t}}{(e^{12t}+1)^2}=(e^{12t}+1)^{-2}e^{12t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that is a little different in that it depends on a knowledge of the hyperbolic functions.

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{e^{12 t}}{e^{24 t} + 2 e^{12 t} + 1} \, dt &= \int \frac{e^{12 t}}{e^{12 t} (e^{12 t} + 2 + e^{-12 t})} \, dt\\
&= \int \frac{dt}{(e^{6t} + e^{-6t})^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{dt}{\left (\dfrac{e^{6t} + e^{-6t}}{2} \right )^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{dt}{\cosh^2 (6t)}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int \text{sech}^2 (6t) \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{24} \tanh (6t) + C.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why are people voting this down? $(1/24)\tanh (6t)=1/24-1/12(e^{12t}+1)$ It is a valid answer and what's more: It's not a duplicate. I'm voting it up.